# not able to upload new version in google play for maui android

Tags: c#, android, maui

When i'm trying upload new version of android maui it says that:

[image]

I've tried to add android:debuggable="false" in application tag inside manifest. it allow me to upload but application is crashing in launch.

```
<application  
    android:debuggable="false"  
    android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"  
    android:allowBackup="true"  
    android:supportsRtl="true"  
    android:label="Test"></application>
```

can someone please help here ?

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: Did you add any nuget packages to your project? If so, in project's `.csproj` file, is there a section `<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net7.0-android'">`? If there is, add to question the contents of that ItemGroup. Should contain one or more `<PackageReference ...>` lines. (Please add as copy/pastable text, not as an image).

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this steps to build a release build of the app: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-google-play#distribute-your-app-through-google-play-console

I have not followed these steps myself. In case you want to build the app using command line (like I do), you can build a release build using this (Windows) batch script, which may help you:

```
@echo off

echo Checklist:
echo 1. Did you update the version and versioncode in the .csproj file? 
echo 2. Make sure you placed the KeyStore file in the root directory of the solution.
echo ==========================
echo:
set /p passwordStore=Enter the password of the Key Store: 
set /p passwordAlias=Enter the password of the Key Alias: 

dotnet publish -f:net7.0-android -c:Release /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=%passwordStore% /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=%passwordAlias%

pause
```

When using the command line way, make sure this PropertyGroup is in your .csproj file (edit to your needs, but leave the Password tags empty ofcourse):

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-android')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>MyKeyStore.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>MyApp</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass></AndroidSigningKeyPass>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass></AndroidSigningStorePass>
</PropertyGroup>
```